# Yii2 - create radioList not enclosed by label

Tags: forms, yii2, radiobuttonlist

How do you create an activeRadioList in yii2 where the checkboxes are not wrapped in labels? Ie. The label and input are adjacent to each other.

The following creates a list of radio buttons where each input is wrapped in labels:

```
<?= $form->field($model,'myattribute')->radioList(['n'=>'No','y'=>'Yes']) ?>
```

You can create one radio button that is not wrapped in a label by setting the second argument to false:

```
<?= $form->field($model,'myattribute')->radio(null,false) ?>
```

But how do you do this for a list? (FYI. I need this to work with the materializedcss framework in case your wondering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to set `label` property `false`

```
<?= $form->field($model,'myattribute')->radioList(['n'=>'No','y'=>'Yes'])->label(false); ?>
```

**Updated answer**

So in that case you need to use custom logic as follows.

```
<?=
        $form->field($model, 'myattribute')
        ->radioList(
                ['n'=>'No','y'=>'Yes'], [
            'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                $return = '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '">';
                $return .= '<i></i>';
                $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                return $return;
            }
                ]
        )
        ->label(false);
?>
```

Comment: This is not correct. It creates 'no label'. The question asks about not 'wrapping' the label (ie. they are adjacent to each other).